# GPU skinning weird issue

Tags: java, shaders, gpu, skinning

I finally got my GPU skinning to work! (Mostly) I'm using MD5 format and this [here](http://3dgep.com/gpu-skinning-of-md5-models-in-opengl-and-cg/) tutorial

However the weird part is that I'm getting EXACTLY the same issue as this unanswered post: [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25098/problem-when-animating-md5-model-gpu-skinning)

The animations are opposite. When the head is supposed to be rotation left/right it rotates up/down and the arm when it goes up seems to look like the vertices invert (backface culling proves it since i can see through the mesh and see the inside of the arm)

Any clues the what might be causing this? Questions?

Comment: My guess is, that the coordinate-system is just not the same (e.g. xzy insteaf of xyz), i'm not sure which coordinate system MD5 uses. Maybe you have to do a little bit rearranging thinks after loading. And about the culling, in openGL, the front face is the face you see, if you draw your triangle by sending the vertices **counterclockwise**, again, i'm not sure how this is in MD5, and again, maybe you have to rearrange things a little bit.

Comment: I found a few posts about this topic, just google "MD5mesh coordinate system", the first result is promising.

Comment: Awesome I'll look into that. And yeah before I started working on the skinning I had to rearrange the triangle indices order.

Comment: Turns out you're right! But I cannot seem to find the correct setup...
I have flipped my axis's on load from xyz to xzy and have tried negating z. Any ideas to the process of changing these left handed coords to right handed?